# Restrict my own webview to use internet

Tags: android, webview

I'm creating an app where I'm connecting to a website (with webview) which uses websockets. I occasionally want to stop the websocket connection and the site kinda supports it like when the user goes offline, it waits for user to come online again to reconnect with websocket.

Now what I'm looking for, is, can I (occasionally) programmatically disable (trigger, actually) my webview (or my app) from accessing internet? I cannot find any API or anything to achieve this.

Please don't recommend to navigate to some other page. I cannot do it because of some critical reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Set WebView's cache mode to [LOAD_CACHE_ONLY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#LOAD_CACHE_ONLY) to disable the network and use cache only.

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);
```

Comment: Its not working. I have a JavaScript interface so I'm directly calling a method which fires this code in Java. Its not making the webview offline.